# Unity WWW(URL) isn't working

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've been searching all day for an answer to my problem. I am trying to use the WWW(URL) in Unity with Javascript to send the scores to my sever from my web player game. I have tried several solutions but I am not sure if I've done any of them right since there wasn't a good explanation on any of it. Here is my code at this moment

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/folder/page.php";

function start(){

        var scoreForm = new WWWForm();
        scoreForm.AddField("score", gamecontroller.score);

        // Sending request:
        var httpResponse = new WWW(url, scoreForm); 

        // Waiting for response:
        yield httpResponse;

var form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField( "score", gamecontroller.score );

var www = new WWW( url, form );

// wait for request to complete
yield www;

// and check for errors
if (www.error == null)
{
    // request completed!
} else {
    // something wrong!
    Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ www.error);
}

}
```

Comment: Should this actually be tagged `[unityscript]` and/or `[unity3d]`? `[unity]` is for a "lightweight, extensible dependency injection container for .NET", while this appears to be a JavaScript-lookalike, which fits the profile of Unityscript. Tagging your question correctly will make it more visible to people who might be able to give you an answer.

Comment: Just read the tag *descriptions* carefully (the tag names alone can be misleading) and select the ones that sound like they apply to your question. Good luck! :)

Comment: I didn't even see those descriptions last time. I did just now when I edited it. Again, thank you.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?  Are you getting errors from `WWW` or is your server not receiving the score?

Comment: I am not getting any errors that I can see. But my server isn't receiving anything. It should have inserted at least the time if the page is activated.